# Outlook Add-in displayDialogAsync works in browser client not in full client

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an Add-in I have written for Microsoft Outlook.  The Add-in runs in a task pane.  I have a button on the html in the page that opens a new window using Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync.  This button works fine in the web client, but when clicked in the full Outlook client, a window appears and disappears in a split second.  This Add-in was developed outside VS so not sure how I can debug apart from in web client, which not does have the issue.

The domain is the same, and the domain is in the appDomain of the XML manifest.  The URL is also https.

Does anyone have any ideas, have I missed something that says this isn't available in full client and only available in web client?

About Outlook version:
Version 2102 (Build 13801.21004 Click-to-Run)
Microsoft Office for Outlook 365 MSO (16.0.13801.21002) 64-bit
If I clock Office Updates, it tells me Office is up to date.

Update
I have another machine with Outlook installed, and I have discovered the dialog opens fine on the full outlook client.  Looking at the version for that version of outlook (logged in to the same Office 365 account), the version shows as:
Version 2110 (Build 14527.20226 Click-to Run)
Microsoft Office for Outlook 365 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20168) 64-bit

So it looks like maybe the earlier build had an issue in Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to share a screen recording in the machine where the API is not working?

Besides, you could also try a test add-in with this: [Manifest](https://kepengtestapp.azurewebsites.net/manifest/AzureOutlook.xml).

It's an app command so you can click "Show Taskpane" first, and then click "launchDialogSameOrigin" button in the taskpane. You can observe whether the dialog is working correctly in this add-in.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Kejing, your plugin had the same issue (great testing app by the way).  I totally uninstalled Outlook and reinstalled, and now the plugin is working. So sadly, I never understood why the issue existed, but it is now resolved.